# How to equal both fields

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am new to VB Net.,. I have two tables.,.,., namely .,., studentsrecords and faculty they both have course field.,.,. I just want to check if that course = course of other table.,.,

```
Dim con As New OleDbConnection
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
    Dim arrImage() As Byte
    Dim myMS As New IO.MemoryStream
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim strcourse As String
    Dim strcourse1

    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

    con = New OleDbConnection(Get_Constring)
    con.Open()

    strcourse = "select Course from facultynew where FacultyID"
    strcourse1 = "select Course from studentsrecords where IDNumber"

    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strcourse, con)
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strcourse1, con)

strcourse=strcourse1
```

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for an [INNER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp).